# DT output takes me to 1st page when i edit a reactive DT

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, dt, shiny-reactivity

I have a toy version of my code below. I have one of the columns (column 7) in my shiny DT output as editable. When i edit the a cell of the column it takes me back to the first row of of the column. I checked the data table object in environment, the edited cell does get update. So, that is good. But i want to stay on the same page after editing the cell. This is because a user may have applied a few filters to reach a certain page and then when he edits a cell he would like to continue from there rather than going back to start.

I am new to R so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using DT 0.7

My data frame has 7 columns: Continent, State, Country, Date, Rate (Pollution), Vehicles, Remark (editable column)

A user can filter the table output by select input, range and slider input. I want to make that output editable.

Thanks in advance!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- navbarPage("Hello",
  tabPanel("Tab1",
           sidebarLayout( 
             sidebarPanel( width = 4,
               selectInput("continent", "Select:",
                           choices = ""),

               selectInput("country" , "Select:",
                            choices = ""),

               selectInput("state" , "Select:",
                           choices = ""),

               dateRangeInput("date", "Select:",
                              startview = "month",
                              minview = "months", 
                              maxview = "decades",
                              start = as.Date('1999-01-01'),
                              end = as.Date(today()),
                              separator = "-"), 

               sliderInput("rate", "Select:",
                           min = 1, max = 5, value = c(1,5), 
                           dragRange = TRUE)),

               mainPanel(
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("Analysis",
                             dataTableOutput("Table1")

           )))))



#server
server <- function(input, output, session)
{

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "continent",
                             choices = c("All", unique(Df$Continent)))
    })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "country",
                      choices = c("All", Df %>%
                        filter(`Continent` == input$continent) %>%
                        select(Country)))
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "state",
                      choices = c("All", Df %>%
                        filter(`Continent` == input$continent & 
                                 `Country` == input$country) %>%
                        select(State)))
  })



  #create reactive table
  RecTable <- reactive({

    Df
      if(input$continent != "All") {
        Df <- Df[Df$Continent == input$continent,]
      }

      if(input$country != "All") {
        Df <- Df[Df$Country == input$country,]
      }

      if(input$state != "All") {
        Df <- Df[Df$State == input$state,]
      }

      Df <- Df %>%
        filter(Date >= input$date[1] & Date <= input$date[2]) %>%
        filter(Rate >= input$rate[1] & Rate <= input$rate[2])

      Df})

  output$Table1 <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(RecTable(),
                  rownames = FALSE ,
                  editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(0:6)))) 

  })

  proxy1 <- dataTableProxy('Table1')

  observeEvent(input$Table1_cell_edit, {

    Df <<- editData(Df, input$Table1_cell_edit, 'Table1', rownames = FALSE, resetPaging = FALSE)

     })}

#run
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue but it worked for me after editing this line `editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(0:6))))` to `editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(0:5))))`